# Route Controller function to welcome.blade file

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a function to generate the chart in a TestChart.php controller.
now i need to call that function in my welcome.blade file. but i don't know how to do that.All i get is that the genChart function is undefined(welcome.blade file)

The genChart function is what is want to call in the welcome.blade file

Controller(where the chart is created):

```php
 public function index()
    {
        $columns = array();
        $charts = array();
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $charts[$column] = $this->genChart("ami_demo2018", $column);
        }

        return view('welcome')->with('charts', $charts);
    }


    function genChart($table, $column)
    {
        $labels = Array();
        $data = Array();
        $distinct = DB::select("select distinct `{$column}` FROM `{$table}`");
        $sql = "SELECT ";
        foreach ($distinct as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
                $sql .= "SUM(case when `{$column}` = '{$value1}' THEN 1 END ) AS `{$value1}`,";
                if (empty($value1)){
                    $value1 = 'Niet ingevuld';
                }
                    array_push($labels, $value1);
            }
        }
        $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
        $sql .= " From {$table}";

        $result = DB::select($sql);
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
                array_push($data, (int)$value);
            }
        }


        $chart = new chart();
        $chart->labels($labels);
        $chart->dataset('First Dataset', "bar", $data);

        return $chart;
    }
```

the welcome.blade file(where i want to call the genChart function):

```php
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
        $selected_val = $_GET['select'];
        genChart($table, $selected_val);
    }
    ?>
</div>
<div id="container">
    @foreach($charts as $chart)
        {!! $chart->container() !!}
        {!! $chart->script() !!}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Make a route in `web.php` and assign that route to a anchor tag in your welcome.blade.php view file.

Comment: How would that route look like? i already tried that but it did not work for me

Comment: You are going about in an incorrect way. You shouldn't really call a controller function like that from a view. You need to create a route for that. Also, using Ajax for calling `genChart()` might be beneficial.

Comment: `Route::get('generate-charts',['as' => 'gen-charts','uses' => 'TestChart@genChart']);` and in your view file, you could do it as `<a href='{{ route('gen-charts') }}'>Generate Charts</a>`

Comment: @vivek_23 i dont have a page called gen-charts, so when i press it it returns a 404 not found

Comment: @beep Define the route as shown in the comment in your `routes/web.php` file.

Comment: @vivek_23 i did

Comment: @beep Is it working or not?

Comment: @vivek_23 no it is not

Comment: @beep What's the error message? I also found that you have 2 parameters `$table` and `$column`. You will have to take care about that too in your route definition.

Comment: @vivek_23 the error message is 'Call to undefined function genChart()' , and my editor says that the function is undefined and also is  the $table variable

Comment: @beep When you render the anchor link it in your view, can you decide what should be the table and the column? Based on that, you will have to edit your route definition as well as route link in your blade file.

Comment: @vivek_23 i want to create a dynamical chart , thats why i needed the genChart function in the first place, i wanted to generate the charts and add the column through a dropdown menu

Comment: define your function in helpers file instead of controller then you can access that funtion from anywhere without any object or $this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$this->getChart()` and defining it as a normal function. You will need to define it as a class function.

Change:

```
function genChart($table, $column)
```

To:

```
public function getChart($table, $column)
```

This will define it as a class function/method.

Comment: It still says that genChart is undefined in my welcome.blade file

Comment: You shouldn't be firing the method from your blade file as it not accessible to the blade template. Your code already passing the function data into a `$charts` array. Looping through the array within blade will allow you to output this data.

Answer (score 0):

First write a route in web.php

```
Route::post('/getChart/{table}/{selected_val}',ControllerName@genChart)->name('genChart');
```

After that in blade file on submit write the route

```
route('genChart',['table'=>$table,'selected_val'=>$selected_val])
```

Make your function genChart public to access...

```
i.e public function genChart()
```

Comment: this looks like it could work but i think there is still something wrong with the route, the method 'name' was not found and the genChart at the end is a undefined constant(i dont know what this means) , also $table is still undefined

Comment: Route::post('/getChart/{table}/{selected_val}',ControllerName@genChart)->name('genChart'); sry for typing mistake add your name in single quote